# how to print above line in logfile?

Tags: string, for-loop, logging

with `open("xxxxx","r")` as `f :`

```
 for n,lines in enumerate(f):
        if lines.__contains__("ERROR"):
            x=lines.split("|")
            print("ERROR:-\n""Time of error: ",x[0])
            print("Cause of error: ", x[3].split(":")[-1])
```

this is printing the lines having error but I need the name of it which is in previous line and even before that how can I print that??

I tried for loop but I need a solution to print lines before the error line. there is a word block and I want that when for loop reaches the error line it also prints the last line in which block word is being used.